# Why Are Changes / Updates to User Account Fields Not Persisted (Lost on Page Refresh)

Tags: 7, forms, users

Drupal version 7.52.

Updating a user account page, e.g. changing their email or name, results in the page being reloaded with the changes persisted in the form, but when you refresh the page the changes are lost.

It's as if some validation errors are blocking the user update function but no feedback is being displayed.

Checked all logs and no errors reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was down to Clientside Validation modules. I disabled the following and it now works as expected:

- `clientside_validation_fapi`
- `clientside_validation_field_validation`

The other clientside validation modules work fine, just these two seem to block updates to user accounts with no errors, warnings or notices.

Comment: I guess they may be developer modules enabled when Drush updated the module.